# What is the best way in Silerlight to make areas of a large graphic clickable?

Tags: silverlight, image

In a **Silverlight** application I have large **images** which have **flow charts** on them.

I need to handle the clicks on specific **hotspots** of the image where the flow chart boxes are.

Since the flow charts will always be different, the information of where the hotspots has to be **dynamic**, e.g. in a list of coordinates.

I've found article like [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/Silverlight_Image_Map.aspx) but don't need the detail of e.g. the outline of countries but just simple **rectangle** and **circle** areas.

I've also found articles where they talk about **overlaying** an HTML **image map** over the silverlight application, but it has to be easier than this.

**What is the best way to handle clicks on specific areas of an image in silverlight?**

Answer (score 1):

Place the Image and a Canvas in a Grid so that the Canvas overlays the Image.

Add shapes of appropriate sizes and placed as needed to the canvas.  All shapes will a transparent fill and no border, hence the user only sees the Image.  On the Canvas MouseDown (or Up events) use `OriginalSource` to determine which shape generated the click.  Use the `Tag` property of each shape to associate it with some object that represents the flowchart element being mapped.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way to do this without a canvas:

[How to get the coordinates of an image mouse click in the event handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452941/how-to-get-the-coordinates-of-an-image-mouse-click-in-the-event-handler/2453011#2453011)