# How to get the coordinates of an image mouse click in the event handler?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, mouse

In the following **WPF** app, I have an **Image** in a **ContentControl**. When the user clicks on the **image**, how can I get the **x/y coordinates** of where the **mouse** clicked on the image?

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestClick828374.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel Margin="10">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding TheImage}" MouseDown="ContentControl_MouseDown"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Code-Behind:**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TestClick828374
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region ViewModelProperty: TheImage
        private Image _theImage;
        public Image TheImage
        {
            get
            {
                return _theImage;
            }

            set
            {
                _theImage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TheImage");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;

            TheImage = new Image();
            TheImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"c:\test\rectangle.png"));
            TheImage.Stretch = Stretch.None;
            TheImage.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;

        }

        #region INotifiedProperty Block
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        #endregion

        private void ContentControl_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            //how to get the coordinates of the mouse click here on the image?
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Found it:

```
Point clickPoint = e.GetPosition(TheImage);
```

Here's my full code example showing the solution:

http://www.tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=codeExamples&id=364

Comment: Alternatively u can use Mouse.GetPosition(TheImage) inside method that has no MouseEventsArgs or MouseButtonEventArgs